# jquery mobile multiple selection, how to alert the choices on close?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am sorry for the noob questions, however I can't figure this out by myself.

I am using  jquery mobile multiple selection and I am having problem to figure so basic stuff (I think this basic), its probably because I am new to javascript.

Here the code I am using :

```
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="font-weight: 700; margin-top: -10px;margin-bottom: -20px;">      
        <select name="day" id="day" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="true">
          <option>Day</option>
          <option value="mon">Monday</option>
          <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
          <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
          <option value="thu">Thursday</option>
          <option value="fri">Friday</option>
          <option value="sat">Saturday</option>
          <option value="sun">Sunday</option>
        </select>
  </div>
```

1. After I changed data-native-menu (from the above code) to true from false the text inside the button that opens the select is gone,is there a way to bring that back or put another text ?
2. And the most impotent! Can anyone show me an example of how to simply alert the choices that the user have did ? and if possible I want to do the alert then the select box is closed after the user have selected the items.

I am sorry for my English, if I didn't explain myself good just comment and I will try again.

Comment: figured out how to alert the selected items, but still having bad time making on close event, and help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple select I think it is best to use `data-native-menu="false"`.  jQM then creates a popup with an ID of the selectID plus "-listbox-popup".  So in your example, the select has an ID of "day"; therefore jQM creates a popup with an ID of "day-listbox-popup". You can now handle the popup widget **[afterclose event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-afterclose)**.

```
<select name="day" id="day" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" >
  <option>Day</option>
  <option value="mon">Monday</option>
  <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="thu">Thursday</option>
  <option value="fri">Friday</option>
  <option value="sat">Saturday</option>
  <option value="sun">Sunday</option>
</select>

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){

    $(document ).on( "popupafterclose", "#day-listbox-popup", function( event, ui ) {
        alert($("#day").val());
    } );

});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3wqcxebf/)**

Comment: This works perfectly, but for me I had to change the "#day-listbox-popup" just to "#day-listbox". Thank you ! Can you explain why the false on the data-native-menu ? will this code work on true state ?

Comment: In true state, jQM does not create a popup, it just uses the select as a list. If you look at the fiddle, it does not work well with multiple...